# Distance calculation when accelerometer and gyroscope work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am testing accelerometer and gyroscope in unity. In my game, 3d balls from the center of the screen fly to the target behind the screen (the target is an empty gameobject with adjusted coordinates).
The movement of the balls is registered in the update, using the usual change in coordinates.

An image with a background has been added to the scene, which I rotate depending on the operation of the accelerometer / gyroscope:

```
float curSpeed = Time.deltaTime * _speed;

if (Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.x) > noTiltWindow)
   _localRotation.z += Input.acceleration.x * curSpeed;
else
   _localRotation.z += Input.acceleration.x * (curSpeed / 2);

bg.transform.rotation = _localRotation;
```

There are no problems with turning. The idea is to change the direction of the balls depending on the rotation of the smartphone.

Now I just take the angle of rotation of the background and calculate the coordinate y, on which I then start up the balls.

```
Vector3 temp = new Vector3();
float angle = bgTransform.localEulerAngles.z;
angle = (angle > 180) ? angle - 360 : angle;
temp.y = angle;
```

At first glance, it works, but not at all the way I want.
It is necessary that when turning the smartphone, the balls are tied to the angle of rotation of the accelerometer or gyroscope.

According to my idea, knowing the distance traveled when turning the smartphone, it will be possible to direct the balls in the right direction.

Is there a way to find out the distance traveled when turning? And how generally this idea with distance is correct?

Comment: Accelerometer and gyroscope are different sensors, the `Input` class has a `gyro` property.

Comment: I know. The fact is that some inexpensive phones do not have a gyroscope sensor, so I want to try to do this for both sensors.